How can I maintain consistent formatting for the axis values in both the actual Plotly.js chart and the downloaded image?
I have provided the code where I am plotting 9 traces using Plotly.js and have
formatted the Y-axis scale by calling formatYAxisScale. However, the formatting is not retained when I download the image. Could I get some insight on why this is
happening and how I can ensure the Y-axis formatting is preserved in
the downloaded image?
import { Directive, ElementRef, Input, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import * as Plotly from 'plotly.js-dist-min';
import { CurrencyFormatterPipe } from '../pipes/currency-formatter.pipe';

@Directive({
  selector: '[appUndiscountedCashflowPlotly]',
})
export class UndiscountedCashflowPlotlyDirective implements OnInit {
  @Input() public data: any;
  protected plot: any;

  constructor(
    protected elementRef: ElementRef,
    private currencyFormatterPipe: CurrencyFormatterPipe
  ) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.plot = this.elementRef.nativeElement;
    const labels = this.data.map((entry: { Year: any }) => entry.Year);

    const trace: any = [];

    const layout: Partial<Plotly.Layout> = {
      barmode: 'relative',
      showlegend: true,
      legend: {
        orientation: 'h', /// Horizontal layout
        yanchor: 'top', /// Align to the top of the legend box
        y: 1.4, /// Align legends to the bottom
        xanchor: 'left',
        x: 0, /// Align legends to the left
        font: { size: 12 },
        traceorder: 'normal',
      },
      autosize: true,
      xaxis: {
        title: {
          text: 'Year',
          font: { size: 14, color: '#000000' },
        },
        tickfont: { size: 12, color: '#000000' },
        tickmode: 'linear', /// Use linear mode for ticks
        dtick: 1, /// Set tick interval to 1
        fixedrange: true,
        showline: true,
      },     
      yaxis: {
        title: {
          text: 'Millions',
          font: { size: 14, color: '#000000' },
          standoff: 20, /// Adds space between the title and the axis
        },
        tickfont: { size: 12, color: '#000000' },
        showline: true,
        zeroline: true,
        fixedrange: true,
        automargin: true,
      },
      margin: {
        t: 30,
        b: 50,
        l: 30,
        r: 30, /// Adjust margins for better layout
      },
      dragmode: undefined, /// Disable dragging for zoom/pan
      plot_bgcolor: '#F8F8F8',
      paper_bgcolor: '#F8F8F8',
    };

    const options: Partial<Plotly.Config> = {
      responsive: true,
      displayModeBar: true,
      modeBarButtonsToRemove: [
        'select2d',
        'lasso2d',
      ] as Plotly.ModeBarDefaultButtons[], // Disable box and lasso select
      toImageButtonOptions: {
        format: 'png',
        filename: 'Cashflow Breakdown (Undiscounted)',
        width: 1000,
        scale: 1,
      },
      displaylogo: false,
    };

    Plotly.newPlot(this.plot, trace, layout, options)
    .then(() =>
      this.formatYAxisScale()
    );

    /// Listen to the relayout event
    this.plot.on('plotly_relayout', () => {
      this.formatYAxisScale(); // Reapply formatting after plot resize or layout change
    });

    /// Listen to the restyle(legend click) event
    this.plot.on('plotly_restyle', () => {
      this.formatYAxisScale(); // Reapply formatting after plot resize or layout change
    });
  }

  ///Format y axis currency
  private formatYAxisScale() {
    const yTicks = this.plot.querySelectorAll('.ytick text');
    yTicks.forEach((tick: any) => {
      const sanitizedValue = tick.__data__.text
        .replace(/−/g, '-')
        .replace(/,/g, '');
      const numericPart = parseFloat(sanitizedValue);
      const suffix = sanitizedValue.match(/[a-zA-Z]+/g)
        ? sanitizedValue.match(/[a-zA-Z]+/g)[0]
        : '';
  
      if (!isNaN(numericPart)) {
        if (suffix === 'M' && numericPart > 0 && numericPart < 1) {
          const convertedValue = numericPart * 1000; /// .2M => 200, .4M => 400
          tick.textContent = `${convertedValue}K`;
        } else if (suffix === 'M' && numericPart < 0) {
          const absoluteValue = Math.abs(numericPart);
          tick.textContent = `$(${absoluteValue})`; /// Display as $(6)
        } else {
          let formattedValue = this.currencyFormatterPipe.transform(
            numericPart,
            true,
            false,
            true,
            true
          );
          if (formattedValue !== null) {            
            if (suffix !== 'M') { /// For positive values with suffix, just add the suffix back
              formattedValue += suffix;
            }
            tick.textContent = formattedValue;
          }
        }
      }
    });
  }   
}


You are modifying the tick text in the DOM but plotly will always generate/update the DOM from the data and layout objects you provide (+ some defaults). You need to set the tick settings in layout.yaxis. See Formatting Ticks in JavaScript.

I tried this approach, but I want to implement conditional formatting, such as displaying negative values in brackets, omitting units for values in millions, and showing them otherwise. This is where I am encountering issues.
